# Int64_t overflow problem

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++

I use Eclipse CDT - Cross G++ Complier (MinGW/msys) on Windows 7, this is my code:

```
int64_t y = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 4;
std::cout << "type id: " << typeid(y).name() << "; value: " << y << "; size of y: " << sizeof(y) << std::endl;
```

(The IDE warning: "Integer overflow".)

And output is:

```
"type id: x; value: 0; size of y: 8"
```

I dont understand, why size of y is 8 bytes but value is 0.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You should explicitly cast the literal to `int64_t`:

```
int64_t y = (int64_t)1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 4;
```

as `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 4` literal is `int`, not `int64_t`.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you're assigning the result to an `int64_t` is irrelevant.  All that matters is that when you multiply two values of type `int`, the result also has type `int`.  Since all of 1024, 1024, 1024, and 4 are constants of type `int`, the resulting temporary product is computed as an `int`, which overflows.

The solution is to make at least one of those constants an `int64_t`.  The product of an `int64_t` with an `int` is an `int64_t`, so the 64-bitness will cascade through the entire product.  You can do this either with an explicit cast or an *integer suffix*:

```
int64_t y = (int64_t)1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 4;  // explicit cast
int64_t y = 1024ll * 1024 * 1024 * 4;  // integer suffix 'll'
```

The suffix `ll` (or equivalently `LL`) after an integer constant says "this value is really a `long long`".  There's also the `ull` (or `ULL`) suffix, which is used for `unsigned long long`.  Also note that the C language standard guarantees that a `long long` is at least 64 bits.

Comment: For readability, use `1024LL`, not `1024ll`.  And `long long` is required to be at least 64 bits; it's not worth worrying about the possibility that it might not be.

Answer (score 1):

When you write "1024" in a C++ expression, like the one in your question, you write an *integer literal*, the size of which is 4 bytes i.e. 32 bits (like its type would be `int` or `unsigned int`), so the last multiplication by 4 makes the 4-byte integer overflow. Try this instead:

```
int64_t y = ((int64_t)1024) * 1024 * 1024 * 4;
```

Comment: `1024` is of type `int`, which may or may not be 32 bits, which may or may not be 4 bytes.

Comment: In "Eclipse CDT, Cross G++ Complier" there is no "may or may not be" about the size of `int` and it's always some invariant number, most likely 4 bytes. But yes, the C++ Standard does not specify the size of `int` and it's up to the compiler to decide this.

Comment: A minor point: the outer parentheses are unnecessary: `int64_t y = (int64_t)1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 4;`